# Use regex to get a substring within a larger string

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm using ruby to read a file and I need to somehow parse some data from each line and store it in an array. Two example 'lines' from the file are:

```
64.34.145.197 - - [03/Sep/2006:05:31:37 -0400] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.0" 200 56
64.34.145.197 - - [03/Sep/2006:05:31:37 -0400] "GET /manual/mod/mod_autoindex.html HTTP/1.0" 200 39134
```

From this I need to get `/robots.txt` and `/manual/mod/mod_autoindex.html`. Using the following simple RegEx, I've been able to extract `GET /robots.txt` and `GET /manual/mod/mod_autoindex.html` but I can't seem to shake the GET.

```
arr.push(/GET \S+/.match(line))
```

I've tried some look ahead's but i'm pretty much a RegEx n00b. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
arr.push(/(?<=GET )\S+/.match(line))
```

If the `HTTP` is guaranteed to follow the url you might also do this to further "frame" the match:

```
arr.push(/(?<=GET )\S+(?= HTTP)/.match(line))
```

`(?<=...)` and `(?=...)` are called [positive lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), btw.

Comment: just refreshed the page to say that i found the answer...and this is what I found. Thanks!